# retrieve actual font name in ios

Tags: html, ios, ios7, uifont

Currently i am trying to get the font name from the UILabel but i am getting font name word inserted like **Interface** and **P4**

For example i am getting

**.HelveticaNeueInterface-MediumP4** as font.fontName but i want **HelveticaNeue-Medium** which is actual name of the font.

The reason is i am generating HTML from UIView and obviously HTML can not identify **.HelveticaNeueInterface-MediumP4** as font. Is there any property available which can give me actual name of the font.

Here is my code

```
UIButton *button = (UIButton *) tempView;
UIFont *font = [button.titleLabel font];
NSString *fontString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"font-family: %@;", font.fontName];
```

Comment: Try with `font.familyName`.

Comment: It always returns ".Helvetica Neue Interface" which is wrong too....

Comment: Then there is no other way to get the desired name except removing `Interface` and `P4` from string via code.

Comment: p4 is not fixed ... it can be m2 m3 p2 p3 and other ...

Comment: It returns the correct value if you implicitly set it + `[button.titleLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"HelveticaNeue-Medium" size:16]];`

Comment: @WilliamGeorge I am not setting it. Somebody else is. I am generating HTML from UIView with same UI elements. :(

Comment: @mihirmehta Thats a shame, I have been looking into this as I was quite interested. It appears to have started happening since iOS7 presumably todo with the new UIFontDescriptors - All system fonts will display the odd internal fonts. So, if the user is not using system fonts, your code should be fine. If they are then it will break. Perhaps then you can check its if its a system font, then update your fontString accordingly.

Comment: Thanks @WilliamGeorge ... I will do that ... Do you have any link or apple doc where apple has mention this styles like p4, p3, m2, m3 etc ... I don't know how many such styles are there...